# Dynamically hide div field if empty using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div>Claim Number: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[ClaimNo]</b></div>
<div>Employee Name: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[EmployeeName]</b></div><div>Loss Date: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[LossDate]</b></div>
<div>Insured Name: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[InsuredName]</b></div>
<div>Jurisdiction State: <b style="background-color: inherit;">
[JurisdictionState]</b></div>
<div>Supervisor: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[Supervisor]</b></div>
<div>Claim Handler: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[ClaimHandler]</b></div>
<div>Claim Status: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[ClaimStatus]</b></div>
<div><br></div><div>First Date Of Incapacity: <b>[FirstDayOfIncapacity]</b></div>
<div>Return To Work Date: <b>[ReturnToWorkDate]</b></div><div><span style="font-family: &quot;Jost*&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">Number Of Weeks: </span><b style="font-family: &quot;Jost*&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">[NumberOfWeeks] </b></div><div>Weeks Of Incapacity:<b style="background-color: inherit;"> [WeeksOfIncapacity]</b></div>
<div>Days Of Incapacity: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[DaysOfIncapacity]</b></div>
<div>Calculated Return To Work Date: <b>[CalculatedReturnToWorkDate] </b></div>
<div><br></div><div>Calculated By: <b>[CalculatedBy]</b>     Calculated On: <b>[CalculatedOn]</b></div>
```

I have a number of items that get dynmically added from a database for each one of the fields within each element. Now, there is for example the DaysOfIncapacity field that is sometimes empty and has no data. I want to have that field hidden if it is empty.

Comment: If the element is truly empty you could use `:empty` selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to hide the whole div when a inner child is empty, then you can't use `:empty` pseudoclass because the `div` itself wouldn't be empty.

So if you want a CSS-only solution the workaround is to print the value also as an attribute of the `div` element

```
<div data-value="[DaysOfIncapacity]">
    Days Of Incapacity: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[DaysOfIncapacity]</b>
</div>
```

and hide the element when the attribute is empty, e.g.

```
div[data-value=""] { display: none }
```

---

Otherwise you need to use JS: cycle over all the `<b>` elements, read their `.textContent` properties and hide the parents element, if necessary

```js
var b = document.querySelectorAll('b');
[...b].forEach((data) => {
   if (data.textContent === '') {
     data.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
     //or add a class that hides the element
   }
});
```

```html
<div>Amount 1 <b>100</b></div>
<div>Amount 2 <b></b></div>
<div>Amount 3 <b>200</b></div>
```

Comment: So the way I would have to input it is like this? <script>
div[data-value=""] { display: none }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-value="[DaysOfIncapacity]">
    Days Of Incapacity: <b style="background-color: inherit;">[DaysOfIncapacity]</b>
</div>

Comment: **<style>** div[data-value=""] { display: none } **</style>**

Answer (score 1):

I am affraid it is not possible to hide `div` (parent) according to `b` (child) element's content.

You need to use Javascript for this:

- find all `b` elements and check their content
- if it is empty hide parent `div` by setting `display: none;` css property.